# Como Alterar Background do Action Bar Top Andoid Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Preciso fazer esse layout, cujo design não é meu já concegui alterar o icone do overflow, porém preciso colocar essa barra verde com essa imagem, sendo ela um botão, por enquanto só preciso do layout, parte de java e funcionalidades ainda não. Sou novato na Programação quem puder dar uma ajuda.

Imagem do layout do projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei usar:

```
<style name="Theme.PlugLightApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar.Bridge">
   <item name="windowActionBar">@drawable/imgappbartop</item>
</style>
```

E também tentei a sugestão de um colaborador da comunidade @cd1:

```
<style name="Theme.PlugLightApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar.Bridge">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.PlugLightApp.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="Widget.PlugLightApp.ActionBar" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.ActionBar.Primary">
    <item name="background">@drawable/imgappbartop</item>
</style>
```